# How to 2-way bind a Dictionary<enum, bool> to a ListView column in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a type like this:

```
public class EffectViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<ShaderType, bool> ShaderSupport { get; set; }
}
```

`.Name` and `.Category` is already binded to 2 separate columns, but the `ShaderSupport` dictionary isn't.

I can't figure out how to 2-way bind the dictionary to a separate column for each `ShaderType`. I don't know if these number of columns can be done dynamically but I hardcoded them in the xaml, so like:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="GPU" >
<GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Pixel" >
...
```

But now stuck on the binding part. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to remove the `=` in `ShaderSupport = { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AllEffects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="NameColumn" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="CategoryColumn" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Column="1" />
                </Grid>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ShaderSupport}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This will create a grid without a header. In order to make checkbox bound in `TwoWay` mode replace dictionary with your own type, `KeyValuePair` doesn't allow to write `Value` property and hence cannot be used for `TwoWay` binding.

Please note that each `EffectVM` should have all Shaders in the dictionary in the same order.

Comment: @Joan, so do you effectively need a grid where rows will represent `Effects` and columns will be `Name, Category, GPU, Pixel, etc.`?

Comment: Yep exactly, and each EffectViewModel will fill .Name, .Category using the appropriate properties with the same name, and where the GPU, Pixel, etc columns will be populated (checked or unchecked) based on the values stored in ShaderSupport for each ShaderType.

Comment: So Blur will look like "Blur" "Smooth" <unchecked> <checked> ... then comes the next effect to another row, etc.

Comment: @Joan, rewritten the entire XAML

Comment: @Snowbear, will try it now. Is it ok to just use Dictionary for now? It wouldn't crash or return compile errors, right? I want to test the binding and if it reads correctly, then I will switch to my type for write.

Comment: @rene, It would not crash with this XAML, but checkboxes will not update binding source

Comment: @Snowbear, thanks again. Also I was using something like:     <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllEffects}"> will this go inside ListView (after deleting ItemsSource attribute)?

Comment: Also I am using GridViewColumns, is it hard to adapt it to those? I use them because they had headers, not sure if they are the best way to show headers and columns.

Comment: @Joan, with this code you will have to create a headers on your own - just add another grid on top of root `ItemsControl`. The problem with `GridViewColumns` is that I see no way to bind it, though maybe there is some way.

Comment: @Snowbear, thanks. Your solution seems pretty good, and I also don't know if GridViewColumns support this. I will see if I can add another grid on top of root ItemsControl like you said.

Comment: @Snowbear: when you specify Value in <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" />, how does it work? I ask this because you never specified the enum EffectType but it would still figure out that it needs to do this per enum? Just trying to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Since dictionary is an IEnumerable you can bind the key and value.  That said order is not always consistent with dictionaries so I would have my view model create a wrapper observablecollection

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ShaderSupport}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Key" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This will produce a two-column ListView.  I believe the OP wants multiple columns with each ShaderType in its own column.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use the ShaderSupport inside another type, since it's for extra columns.

Comment: Have you tried FrameworkElementFactory.  It allows you to create data templates/control templates in a manner that's very declarative.